# is_null function is not working in object values

Tags: php, loops, object

I would like to loop through an object like this

```
 0 => 
object(stdClass)[13]
  public 'first_name' => string 'toto' (length=7)
  public 'last_name' => string 'titi' (length=7)
  public 'phone_1' => null
1 => 
object(stdClass)[14]
  public 'first_name' => string 'tutu' (length=7)
  public 'last_name' => string 'tata' (length=8)
  public 'phone_1' => string '123' (length=9)
```

This object come from a PDO::FetchAll(PDO::fetchobject).

My foreach loop:

```
foreach($users as $user){
    echo (!is_null($user->phone)) ? $user->phone : '';
}
```

But I got this error message: **trying to get property 'phone_1' of non-object in**

May someone help me for this ?

Thank you

Comment: Well the error means `$people` is null (or at least, isn't an object). You didn't show us where `$people` comes from or how it gets populated (hint: it probably doesn't).

Comment: @ADyson $people is a result from a fecthALL(PDO:: FETCH_OBJECT)

Comment: Re your edit: Do some debugging. `var_dump($user);` inside your `foreach` loop to see what it _actually_ contains, not what you assume it does.

Comment: @ADyson this object in the description is the var_dump

Comment: `this object in the description is the var_dump `...the var_dump in your question shows an array (containing 2 objects), not an object.

Comment: Also your error message doesn't match your code. Your code tries to access `->phone` but the error message talks about `phone_1`. So you're not showing us the real code. Don't re-type your code for your question, always copy and paste it.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
echo (!is_null($user->phone)) ? $user->phone : '';
```

... can be simplified to:

```
echo $user->phone;
```

If the property is `null`, it'll cast automatically to empty string (`''`).

If you get `trying to get property 'phone' of non-object`<sup>1</sup> it's because you don't have an object to begin with. That's a different problem.

If you're looping the results of a database query, you shouldn't need to check for object existence, and doing so might mask a bug in some other part of your code. A possible cause is that your query is failing and [fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns `false`.

<sup>1</sup> *Please note I've fixed the property name in the error message, assuming it was a copy+paste error. If you really read `phone` and get an error about `phone_1`, you didn't check the correct line.*

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
 <?php echo isset($user->phone) ? $user->phone : ''; ?>
```

Comment: or faster :  ($user->phone) ?? ''